# Show Zero in input type Time

Tags: html, input, time

I would like to show only `00:00` in input type time. My code is like below.

```
<input class="form-control" type="time" value="00:00" required>
```

I am getting output like below.

[image]

Comment: Please share the proper code snippet, check your code if any JS is setting this on runtime. Looking at your input element it should display default time as "00:00". Also do check if any plugin or JS might be overriding this option on page/document  ready/load.

Comment: Thanks @NikhilSawant. Could you please show any sample code in this regard ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfectly, see below snippet.

Things you can verify inside your code:

- Check your code if any JS is setting ("12:00")this on runtime. Looking at your input element it should display default time as "00:00".
- Also do check if any plugin or JS might be overriding this option on page/document ready/load event.
- Check default time format in your system, It's based on 24-hour time or 12-hour time.

```html
<input class="form-control" type="time" value="00:00" required>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nikul Sawant. Is it my browser issue or my OS issue ? I can see your output like this.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRgv6.png.  What are you seeing ? I would like to show `00:00` this format. Thanks.

Comment: Check default time format in your system, It's based on 24-hour time or 12-hour time.

Comment: Thanks @Nikhil Sawant. But I would like to show like `01:00` means 1 hour or `00:30` means 30 minutes. How can I do that ?